# Way to download GDOC or Folder from Drive?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs

I want to automatically download 2 .gdoc files from my drive

I want to download 2 .gdoc files from my drive via python, which can be downloaded as folder/pdf/docx. I've tried it with the help of the google drive api documentation, but I didn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you mount google drive locally using google file stream? Then you can try something like:

```
src = source path
dest = dest path
os.chdir(src)
    for file in os.listdir('.'):
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
             sh.copy(file, dest)
```

Comment: I've already added it locally, but the problem is in the folder is only the .gdoc file.
The Problem with this is that I'm not able to get it as a format which i can work with